# Can we make EC2 instances in the web tier as Private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

We have Typical 3 tier architecture having Web, App and DB.
Can we make EC2 instances in the web tier as Private? and allow incoming traffic only through ALB?
AFAIK we can apply an SG only allowing connections from the SG of the ALB. But What if our Private EC2 instance has to return response back to the client? How it'll be routed through ALB as ALB is mostly used for managing incoming traffic.
Also for outgoing traffic can we configure something like Private EC2 instance -> ALB -> Internet? If yes then how? So, is there any way for private EC2 instances to communicate to internet without assigning them public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your instances in a private subnet is best practice, even for the web layer.

For inbound traffic you would add a load balancer into your public subnets then allow HTTP/HTTPS ingress on the webs security group only from the load balancer. You can either do this through adding the subnet ranges into the web servers security group, or reference the security group the load balancer has assigned to it instead.

For outbound internet traffic in a private subnet you will need to create either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) within a public subnet, and then add a route for `0.0.0.0/0` for the private subnet to route traffic to the NAT. Additionally if you want IPv6 traffic you would create an [egress only internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/egress-only-internet-gateway.html) with a route of `::/0`.

Answer (score 2):

> But What if our Private EC2 instance has to return response back to the client? How it'll be routed through ALB as ALB is mostly used for managing incoming traffic.

You don't have to do anything special, assuming your ALB and instances are correctly set. Any request coming to ALB, will be able to return to the client event if instances are in private subnet without any internet connectivity.

However, your instance won't be able to initiate internet connections by themselves. So if the instances don't need internet to operate, you don't need NAT. Otherwise, it is required.